# Updating Memberpress expiry date after transaction created

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravityforms, memberpress

I want to assign a Memberpress expiry date 1 (or 2) years from the current expiry date instead of adding the years to today's date, which is the default behaviour.

I am using gravity forms with gravity press to register members. In the form, I grab the current expiry date, add the appropriate number of years to it, and put it into another field what goes into usermeta when the form is saved.

I am trying to use the following code to update the expiry date when the transaction is complete.

Am I on the right track?

````
 $transaction = $event->get_data();
 $user = $transaction->user();

 if(($subscription = $transaction->subscription_id)) {
   $subscription_number = $subscription->subscr_id;
   //This transaction belongs to a recurring subscription
 }
 else {
   $transaction_number = $transaction->trans_num;
   //This is a non-recurring transaction
 }

global $wpdb;

$newdate = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT yearFromNow FROM usermeta WHERE userid = ".$user. "and meta_key = 'mepr_mepr_yearfromnow' " ), 0);

$insertdate = mysql_result(mysql_query("INSERT into wp_mepr_transactions max(expires_at) value ".$newdate." into WHERE userid = ".$user ), 0);


}
add_action('mepr-event-transaction-completed', 'mepr_capture_completed_transaction'); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries should be checked for errors before assuming there is a result in the return value.

Always look doing the most in SQL rather than retrieving to PHP and then reusing data. For example in your case there is an [INSERT .. SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) that may be of use.

Pay attention to the syntax, your `INSERT` statement doesn't conform to a existing syntax and its hard to work out what was intended.

Comment: I changed the insert statement to this:  `$insertdate = mysql_result(mysql_query("INSERT into wp_mepr_transactions expires_at value ".$newdate." WHERE userid = ".$user . "and ". $transaction. "== trans_num" ), 0);`  I am going to work on changing it to INSERT .. SELECT, as you suggested.  Now, I just have to figure out why it isn't inserting the new date if the membership is one they haven't had before.